# Choosing the class for the list and setting only one of them

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to set a class with the font name chosen from the list. 
When the user is choosing different font the existing class is removed and new class is set.

here is my buggy JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '.fonts-container ul li', function(){ 
   if ( $('.font2').hasClass("active")) {
    var fontName = $(this).data("fontname");
    $(this).closest(".editor").find('.text').toggleClass(fontName);
    }
   }
});
```

here is the list:

```
<ul >
  <li  data-fontname="Aclonica">Aclonica</li>
  <li  data-fontname="Acme">Acme</li>
  <li  data-fontname="Alegreya">Alegreya</li>
</ul>
```

So in the result element text has two classes: .text and the font name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest skipping the class swapping and setting the inline font-family style property using jQuery. Use the `data-fontname` property to specify valid font names instead of class names and set them directly. That way the `font-family` rule is simply overwritten so you don't need to unset the previous value first.

Also, insert a `data-target` attribute on the `ul` element containing the list so the list becomes less sensitive to markup changes.

```
<ul data-target=".editor1">
  <li data-fontname="Aclonica">Aclonica</li>
  <li data-fontname="Acme">Acme</li>
  <li data-fontname="Alegreya">Alegreya</li>
</ul>

$('.fonts-container > ul > li').on('click', function(){
  var $el = $(this);
  var fontName = $el.data('fontname');
  var $target = $($($el.parent()).data('target'));
  $target.css('font-family', fontName);
});
```

There were unexplained parts to your JS that seemed outside the scope of your question so I omitted those for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You have not given all the pieces of html. Here is a simulated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m2rHL/

```
$(document).on('click', '.fonts-container ul li', function(){ 
    var fontName = $(this).data("fontname");
    //alert(fontName + " " + $(".editor").find('.text').length);
    $(".editor").find('.text').addClass(fontName); });
```

Comment: but now the .text has all 3 classes of fonts, i should always have only one.

Comment: @lipenco why don't you make a fiddle, its a better and faster way to get your problem solved

Comment: We can remember the last added class as data attribute. See modified:http://jsfiddle.net/raghavv/m2rHL/2/